# Issue with serializing JSON from a rest call

Tags: java, resttemplate, json-deserialization

Newbie developer here. I am trying to make a call to a public API. The API receives the name of a drink as a string and returns information and recipe for that name. The response from the API looks like this:

```
{
  "drinks":[
     {
        "id": ...
        "name": ...
        "recipe": ...
        "category": ...
        "alcoholic": ...
        ... many other fields ...
     },
     {
        ...
     }
     ...
   ]
}
```

I am only interested in `name`, `recipe` and `category`. I have a domain class for this purpose that looks like this

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Drink {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("category")
    private String category;

    @JsonProperty("recipe")
    private String recipe;

}
```

I also implemented a client to call the endpoint using `restTemplate`. Here is the call that client makes:

```
ResponseEntity<List<Drink>> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                    url,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    null,
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Drink>>() {
                    });
```

My goal is to call the API, get the response and only the fields that I want and store it in a list of `Drink`. However when I try to run the app locally and make a call I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<Drink>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<Drink>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

When I use `ResponseEntity<String>` instead, it works but returns the whole json as a string, which does not seem like a good approach. How can I get this approach to work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mismatch between json structure and object structure. The object you deserialize into must represent correctly the json. It's an object with a field `drinks`, which is an array of objects(drinks in your case). Correct java class would be:

```
public class Wrapper {

  private List<Drink> drinks;

  //getters and setters

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "Wrapper{" +
              "drinks=" + drinks +
              '}';
  }
}
```

Other option would be to write custom deserializer, which can extract `drinks` from the tree before deserializing directly into a list.]

**Edit:** Added `toString()` override for debugging purposes.

Comment: I did this and defined a new ```Wrapper``` class which only has a list of ```Drink```. However now ```response.getBody()``` returns ```Wrapper@46854e06```.

Comment: @Shirin Are you perhaps logging the result with `System.out.println(response.getBody());`, or `response.getBody().toString()`, or something similar? `Wrapper@46854e06` would be the result of `.toString()` call, when the method is not overridden.